# how can i choose cmap to plot variables in netCDF4 file with condition IF?

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf4

I have a netCDF4 file with several variables are IR or VIS variables (infrared or visible channel) I have a code that reads the file netCDF4 and after creating a list_var that allows to put the variables to display, the problem what for the visualization of the infrared channel the cmap I have to choose cmap = plt.cm.gist_yarg and for the visible channel the cmap = plt.cm.gist_gray

I  need  to use the condition if to indicate in case the variable starts with IR or VIS the cmap will change but i don't know how do that for my code :

that the code to show one of variable i choose in list_var :

```
import numpy as np 
import netCDF4 
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
import pylab as plt


fic='Mmultic3kmNC4_msg04_201905080200.nc

path='/home/data/'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(path+fic,'r')

nc.variables.keys() 

print nc.variables.keys()

odict_keys(['time', 'dtime', 'IR_016', 'commentaires', 'satellite', 'geos', 'ImageNavigation', 'GeosCoordinateSystem', 'Y', 'X', 'Albedo_to_Native_count_IR_016', 'IR_039', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_039', 'IR_087', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_087', 'IR_097', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_097', 'IR_108', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_108', 'IR_120', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_120', 'IR_134', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_134', 'VIS006', 'Albedo_to_Native_count_VIS006', 'VIS008', 'Albedo_to_Native_count_VIS008', 'WV_062', 'Temp_to_Native_count_WV_062', 'WV_073', 'Temp_to_Native_count_WV_073'])

vars = [nc.variables['VIS006'],nc.variables['VIS008'],nc.variables['IR_120'],nc.variables['IR_108'],nc.variables['IR_087'],nc.variables['IR_134'],nc.variables['IR_039'],nc.variables['WV_073'],nc.variables['WV_062'],nc.variables['IR_097']]

vars_list = ['VIS006','VIS008','IR_120','IR_108','IR_087','IR_134','IR_039','WV_073','WV_062','IR_097']

vars  = [nc.variables[f] for f in vars_list]

plt.imshow(vars[1],cmap=plt.cm.gist_gray)
```

#(var[1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IT-F7AbIx4bCjMLosjBx4F4UCoIX5DU0) in var_list is = VIS008 so i use cmap=plt.cm.gist_gray)

the line of code if condition that i need to use in my code :

```
if "IR" in var:
            plt.imshow(var[..], cmap=plt.cm.gist_yarg)
elif "VIS" in var:
            plt.imshow(vars[..], cmap=plt.cm.gist_gray)
```

if you have any idea and help to use condition to choose cmap for iR or VIS and show it after !

thank you

the netcdf4 file here : [netcdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IT-F7AbIx4bCjMLosjBx4F4UCoIX5DU0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your current code, you could do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vars_list = ['VIS006','VIS008','IR_120','IR_108','IR_087','IR_134','IR_039','WV_073','WV_062','IR_097']

cmaps = []
for var in vars_list:
    if 'VIS' in var:
        cmaps.append(plt.cm.gist_yarg)
    elif 'IR' in var:
        cmaps.append(plt.cm.gist_gray)
    else: # Make sure we have a default
        cmaps.append(plt.cm.jet)

plt.imshow(vars[1],cmap=cmaps[1])
```

Or, if you are writing a loop over your `vars` list, you could do something like:

```
for var in vars:
    if 'VIS' in var.name:
        cmap = plt.cm.gist_yarg
    elif 'IR' in var.name:
        cmap = plt.cm.gist_gray
    else: # Make sure we have a default
        cmap = plt.cm.jet

    plt.imshow(var, cmap=cmap)
```

Full working example:

```
import netCDF4 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nc = netCDF4.Dataset('Mmultic3kmNC4_msg04_201903090130.nc','r')
vars_list = ['VIS006','VIS008','IR_120','IR_108','IR_087','IR_134','IR_039','WV_073','WV_062','IR_097']
vars  = [nc.variables[f] for f in vars_list]

for var in vars:
    if 'VIS' in var.name:
        cmap = plt.cm.gist_yarg
    elif 'IR' in var.name:
        cmap = plt.cm.gist_gray
    else: # Make sure we have a default
        cmap = plt.cm.jet

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(var, cmap=cmap)
```

And an example of how to plot a single map:

```
import netCDF4 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nc = netCDF4.Dataset('Mmultic3kmNC4_msg04_201903090130.nc','r')
vars_list = ['VIS006','VIS008','IR_120','IR_108','IR_087','IR_134','IR_039','WV_073','WV_062','IR_097']
vars  = [nc.variables[f] for f in vars_list]

cmaps = []
for var in vars_list:
    if 'VIS' in var:
        cmaps.append(plt.cm.gist_yarg)
    elif 'IR' in var:
        cmaps.append(plt.cm.gist_gray)
    else: # Make sure we have a default
        cmaps.append(plt.cm.jet)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(vars[2], cmap=cmaps[2])
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: if i do the second solution is that correct cause i don't get figure after : `In [5]: vars  = [nc.variables[f] for f in vars_list]                            

In [6]: for var in vars: 
     if 'VIS' in var.name: 
          cmap = plt.cm.gist_gray) 
     elif 'IR' in var.name: 
   ...:         cmap = plt.cm.gist_yarg) 
  else: # Make sure we have a default 
     cmap = plt.cm.jet)  plt.imshow(var[1], cmap=cmap) ` thank you

Comment: yeah that good but i can't show figure i don't know how you can show the figure of the variable ? i have question here `plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(var, cmap=cmap)` for var how i can choose the var i want plot i can do var[1] or how  thank you

Comment: with yout example i can plot all variables in the same time but i need to plot just the variable i want , can i do : `plt.imshow(var[1], cmap=cmap)` or not thank you

Comment: I added an example of how to plot a single map

Comment: please for `data.min()` and `data.max()` how i can i do for all here i can do juste for one variable this example : `data = nc['IR_134'][:]

min = data.min()
max = data.max()
cmaps = []
for var in vars_list:
    if 'VIS' in var:
        cmaps.append(plt.cm.gist_gray)
    elif 'IR' in var or 'WV' in var :
        cmaps.append(plt.cm.gist_yarg)
    else: # Make sure we have a default
        cmaps.append(plt.cm.jet)
plt.imshow(vars[5], cmap=cmaps[5],vmin=min,vmax=max)` data = nc['IR_134'][:] how i can do that not for variable IR but for variable i choose ? thank you

Comment: You could do something like `vmins  = [nc.variables[f][:].min() for f in vars_list]` followed by `plt.imshow(vars[5], cmap=cmaps[5],vmin=mins[5], ..)`

Comment: what means `vmin=mins[5]` what mean 5 cause when i run code i get error :  IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

Comment: Sorry, meant `vmin=vmins[5]`

Comment: yeah that meant vmin will have the min value of datamin from the vars[5] , your code is good but do not allow me to change the dynamics because I would like to keep a range of values do not specify vmin = min [5] for example for variable vars [5] because after I'm going to have a button which allows to change this dynamic to enter min and max values to the lines`min = [nc.variables [f] [:]. min () for f in vars_list]
max = [nc.variables [f] [:]. max () for f in vars_list]` and after changing the values each time

Comment: in this example the vmin=min = -6 and vmax=max = 279.59 for vars[5] so what i need is something like : `plt.imshow(vars[5], cmap=cmaps[5],vmin = min,vmax= max)` cause after i will edit the value max and min with button and they  can be changed in the range min =-6 and max=279

Comment: I created an index of variables like that after I put :` mins = [index] & maxs = [index]` and  `plt.imshow(vars[index], cmap=cmaps[index],vmin = min,vmax= max)` and is okey thank you